# Control click for multi-select

Tags: sublimetext3

Ctrl click to multi select is doing nothing for me. I can do ctrl-alt-up/down to get cursors on multiple lines but ctrl click is just not doing anything.

Comment: What build of Sublime and operating system are you using?

Comment: windows 10, 3.2. its a work computer so updating is a pain.

Comment: what packages do you have installed? likely one is rebinding ctrl+click. Try reverting to a clean state to prove it http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/revert.html

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like alterations have been made to your `.sublime-mousemap` file(s). Perhaps by an installed package or by whomever installed Sublime Text on your work computer.

To fix this you need a `Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap` file which contains the following `JSON`.

```js
[
    // Ctrl+SingleClick to add multiple selections.
    // Note: 'button1' refers to the left mouse button
    // and 'count' being set to 1 means a single click.
    {
        "button": "button1", "count": 1, "modifiers": ["ctrl"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "press_args": {"additive": true}
    }
]
```

The easiest way to achieve this is to look in your Sublime Text [data directory](https://docs.sublimetext.io/basic_concepts.html#the-data-directory) tree to see if the `%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap` file exists.

If the file already exists then edit it, otherwise create the file, and add the `JSON` I've posted above.

For reference I have uploaded the full `Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap` file (from Sublime Text build 3211) to a [Gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/mattst/fe763159a809b730da192d99818fe219) - if you look at the 2nd dictionary in the file you'll see it is the `JSON` I've posted above. Please note that you do not need the whole of that file in your `%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap` file just the `JSON` I've posted.